# Unable to get response from php return in ajax request

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I am trying to access the output from php code to jquery ajax. But I donot know why It is returning me whole page html including the result. can anybody please tell me about it. In firefox console Its show me response of page html including php result. But In jquery code console.log does not hit.

Here is jquery code

```
function getprofile()
{
     $.ajax({
            url: 'Userpage/get_profile',
            //data: {'title': title},  change this to send js object
            type: "post",
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {'userid': 1}, 
            success: function(data) { 

            console.log(data);
          }
        });
}
```

My php code

```
   <?php

if (!defined('BASEPATH'))
    exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Userpage extends CI_Controller
{


    function __construct()
    {

        parent::__construct();

        $this->load->helper('url');
        $this->load->helper('form');
        $this->load->library("session");
        $this->load->model("Userpage_model");
        $this->load->view('Userpage_view');
    }

    public function index()
    {

    }


    public function get_profile()
    {
        $data = array();
        $post_id = $this->input->post('userid');
        $data['comments'] = $this->Userpage_model->get_profile($post_id); 
        echo json_encode($data['comments']);
        exit;
    }


}
?>
```

Please review the code and tell me where I am going wrong

Thanks

Comment: please show more/all of your php code!

Comment: please check now @low_rents

Comment: what framework are you using? I don't get how the url in your ajax call `url: 'Userpage/get_profile'` leads to the execution of the method `get_profile()` in your `Userpage` class.

Comment: I am using codeigniter@low_rents

Comment: sorry, i don't have any experience with codeigniter.

Answer (score 1):

Use `exit`

```
public function get_profile()
    {
        $data = array();
        $post_id = $this->input->post('userid');
        $data['comments'] = $this->Userpage_model->get_profile($post_id); 
        echo json_encode($data['comments']);
        exit; // use exit here
    }
```

**EDIT**

PHP uses a special function called `header()` for setting properties of the page during rendering.

Comment: The script keeps running till you exit it http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exit.php

Comment: @azadchauhan if it works just because of the `exit` then there must be an error or unwanted output later in your code.

Comment: @yosefh no, that's not true at all. the PHP script would only keep running when using an endless loop or a recursion - which I can't see here.

Comment: then what is another solution @low_rents

Comment: @azadchauhan I need to see more of your code - specially the PHP code.

Comment: this is all I create.. Its a codeigniter controller in which I just create this function in that controller@low_rents

Comment: Why was this not in the 20 other answers I looked at the last hour? All those answers marked as correct should not have worked.. Is this new or old way of writing?

Answer (score 1):

you need to return from your function, using exit is fine but it's not a good practice

```
public function get_profile()
    {
        $data = array();
        $post_id = $this->input->post('userid');
        $data['comments'] = $this->Userpage_model->get_profile($post_id); 
        return json_encode($data['comments']);
    }
```

Comment: no, returning alone does nothing when "replying" to an ajax-call. if he returns in this method he needs to echo (output) where this method is called.

Answer (score 0):

You are using CI. From this ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'Userpage/get_profile',
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

you expect an ajax call is being made to **get_profile** action inside **Userpage** controller, that probably will return:

```
{
    "comments": [
        { ... },
        { ... },
        { ... },
        ...
    ]
}
```

which will be logged in browser console.

But you get unexpected result, right?

I think, your ajax call results in error. To prove this, modify your ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'Userpage/get_profile',
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        // add this function to logs error
        console.log(textStatus + ': ' + errorThrown);
    }
});
```

Now, if the ajax call results in error, you can see the error in browser console. I am pretty sure you will get **error: Not Found** in browser console.

You are using CI, the URL will be something like:

```
http://<something>/index.php/site/index
```

In this page, if you make ajax call with url Userpage/get_profile, what the browser really does is make ajax call to:

```
http://<something>/index.php/site/index/Userpage/get_profile
```

instead of what you expect:

```
http://<something>/index.php/Userpage/get_profile
```

To solve this, you must change the value of **url** in your ajax call, to point the correct URL above.

By using CI, the absoulte URL above can be generated with the help of **site_url()** function:

```
site_url('Userpage/get_profile')
```

I usually print this URL somewhere in HTML, and retrieve it from javascript during ajax call.

Comment: Yess I got error  unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON data at line 1 column 141 of the JSON data

Comment: You put "exit" after echo json_encode(), but you said "it's returning whole page html including the result". Could you read the whole HTML and guess what page it is? CI often displays error to the browser.

Comment: And also, take a look at application/logs/*.log file. If your page encounters error, it will be logged there.